# Angular Manager Service

Tags: angularjs

I have a page.html with a directive in it.  I also have a service which I want to use as a manager of events between the directive and the page.html controller.

I'm new to Angular so I don't know if I'm approaching this the right way.  I want the service to update the directive if say my controller has a button clicked.  Do I just put the directive as a dependency for my service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to inject your service in your directive.
The service should handle communication with your server or strictly business logic, best you must separate into two services if you have communication and business logic.
Directive is only for the visualization part.

Events should be placed into directive "link" function and visualization functionality into "controller" but remember. Angular is not jQuery so many events like "click" are obsolete in angular by that i mean they handled automatically by a property in the controller.

Comment: My directive has its own controller and my page.html has its own controller.  When an event occurs in my page.html I am trying to call a function in my directive's controller to update based on that event.  Is this something that should not be done?

Comment: @Msbart that depends the best way to communicate controllers is through services. If you have it that way then ok always it depends the case.

Comment: is there a way for my directive to monitor a variable in my service for changes?

Comment: you don't do it the right way. Angular is not event programming like jquery and your logic should be reversed. Only on `scope` you should set watchers. Services are static without any events their purpose is to bring/transform data or make calculations and of course share data between controllers.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a fine approach and is often necessary, since services are singletons and controllers and directives are not. You will inject your service into both your directive **AND** the page controller. This way both can act on the service and the service can act as a bridge between the two.

```
app.service("myService", function() {
    //define your service
});

app.directive('myDirective', function (myMervice) {
    return {
        template: '...',
        restrict: '...',
        scope:true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            //you can use the service here
        }
    };
});

app.controller("myController", function($scope, myMervice) {
    //you can use the service here
});
```